# Token line number = 1,Token line offset = 56,Token in error = select

Tags: sql-server, windows-ce

I'm getting following error while retrieving value from SQL Server Ce:

> Token line number = 1,Token line offset = 56,Token in error = select

Where my query is:-

```
select columnName 
from TableName 
where PrimaryKey=(select max (PrimaryKey) from TableName);
```

Please suggest to me the possible errors.

Comment: What type is PrimaryKey?

Answer (score 0):

The database might not support that type of subquery. Try it without a subquery:

```
select top 1 columnName 
from TableName
order by PrimaryKey desc
```